# Capture HTTP metrics using goRelic agent of custom http handler

Tags: go, newrelic

I was trying to capture the system resources used by http handler, Latency etc. Since there is no newrelic agent for go lang. So, I found this [goRelic](https://github.com/yvasiyarov/gorelic) agent.
Which says using the folowing way i can capture the http metric:

```
agent.CollectHTTPStat  = true
http.HandleFunc("/", agent.WrapHTTPHandlerFunc(handler))
```

But the problem is i am using custom http handler given in the [link](https://elithrar.github.io/article/custom-handlers-avoiding-globals/) as follows:

```
type appHandler struct {
    *appContext
    H func(*appContext, http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) (int, error)
}


func (ah appHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Updated to pass ah.appContext as a parameter to our handler type.
    status, err := ah.H(ah.appContext, w, r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("HTTP %d: %q", status, err)
        switch status {
        case http.StatusNotFound:
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            // And if we wanted a friendlier error page, we can
            // now leverage our context instance - e.g.
            // err := ah.renderTemplate(w, "http_404.tmpl", nil)
        case http.StatusInternalServerError:
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(status), status)
        default:
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(status), status)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    r := web.New()
    // We pass an instance to our context pointer, and our handler.
    r.Get("/", appHandler{context, IndexHandler})     
    graceful.ListenAndServe(":8086", r)    

}
```

So, how do i capture the http metric for this handle or is there any other tool by which i can capture the similar metrics?

Comment: Use `WrapHandler` instead: https://godoc.org/github.com/yvasiyarov/gorelic#Agent.WrapHTTPHandler

Comment: Oops, didn't see that. Thanking by the way

Answer (score 0):

I just need to use `WrapHandler`. Credits to elithrar for the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550590/capture-http-metrics-using-gorelic-agent-of-custom-http-handler/36566893#comment60702130_36550590).

```
agent.CollectHTTPStat  = true
http.HandleFunc("/", agent.WrapHandler(handler)
```